# RasPi + Node.js forever: cannot hear mp3 sound after rebooting

Tags: node.js, audio, raspberry-pi, cron, forever

I have a node.js script that plays a mp3 file with mpg321 triggered by HTTP request on my RasPi 3B and want to run continuously even after rebooting the Pi.

I'm able to play a mp3 file as a background job with forever start command, and also able to run a simple script that does not involve mp3 after rebooting with crontab setting. However, although everything is working fine, the mp3 sound is always missing only when I reboot.

Does anyone know a way to get around this issue?

Node.js script:

```
var mpg321 = require('mpg321');
var filepath = "./audio/beep-01a.mp3";
var player = mpg321().remote();

//infinity loop
player.play(filepath);
player.on('end', function () {
  console.log('end');
  player.play(filepath);
});
```

Crontab settings:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/forever start /home/pi/Documents/nodejs/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause which is interesting.
A relative file path doesn't work when you run it after rebooting although it works perfectly when you run the script explicitly typing a command from the terminal window by yourself. So every path used in your script needs to be an absolute path.
Hope it helps someone who runs into the same problem in the future.